# Windows Phone 8.1 C# Can´t acces textbox from a Hubselection

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I´m working on a Windows Phone 8.1 c# app.
I´m trying to acces a textbox that is inside a tab page of a Hub. But whatever i do i can´t acces the textbox in the MainPage.xaml.cs code. Can anyone tell me why?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Hub x:Name="Hub" Header="My Buddy!" Background="#FF303030">
        <HubSection Tag="0" x:Name="HubSelection" Header="Hoofdscherm">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="btnAgenda" Content="Agenda" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="140" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFD13535" Foreground="White" Click="btnAgenda_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnTaken" Content="Taken" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,17,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="140" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFD13535" Foreground="White" Click="btnTaken_Click"/>

                    <Button x:Name="btnNieuweAfspraak" Content="Nieuwe afspraak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="140" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFD13535" Foreground="White" Click="btnNieuweAfspraak_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnNieuweTaak" Content="Nieuwe taak" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,161,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="140" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFD13535" Foreground="White" Click="btnNieuweTaak_Click"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>



        <HubSection Tag="1" Header="Agenda">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <AppBarButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Add" Label="Nieuwe afspraak" Margin="6,419,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="337" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>



        <HubSection Tag="2" Header="Taken">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <AppBarButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Add" Label="Nieuwe taak" Margin="6,419,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="337" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>



        <HubSection Tag="3" x:Name="NewAfspraak" Header="Nieuwe afspraak">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox x:Name="AfspraakBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" Height="47" PlaceholderText="Naam afspraak" TextChanged="AfspraakBox_TextChanged" IsColorFontEnabled="False"/>
                    <DatePicker x:Name="DatumAfspraak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55" Width="157"/>
                    <TimePicker x:Name="BegintijdAfspraak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="53" Width="159"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="tbLocatieAfspraak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,106,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" PlaceholderText="Locatie" Height="42"/>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="255" Width="321" PlaceholderText="Omschrijving"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnAfspraakOpslaan1" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,436,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="159" Height="63" Click="btnAfspraakOpslaan1_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnAfspraakOpslaan" Content="Annuleren" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,436,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="157" Height="63" Click="btnAfspraakAnnuleren_Click"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>




        <HubSection Tag="4" Header="Nieuwe taak">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TbNaamTaak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" Height="47" PlaceholderText="Naam taak"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tbTaakOmschrijving" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" Height="254" PlaceholderText="Omschrijving"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Eindtijd:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="14" Width="54"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Begintijd:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="14" Width="98"/>
                    <TimePicker x:Name="BegintijdNieuweTaak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="157" Height="55" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Selecteer een begintijd:" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                    <TimePicker x:Name="EindtijdNieuweTaak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" Height="53" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Selecteer een eindtijd:"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnTaakOpslaan" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,436,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="159" Height="63" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Click="btnTaakOpslaan_Click"/>
                    <Button Content="Annuleren" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,436,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="157" Height="63" Click="btnTaakAnnuleren" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                    <DatePicker x:Name="DatumNieuweTaak" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="321" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

And my MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
private void btnTaken_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String Test = AfspraakBox.text;
    Hub.ScrollToSection(Hub.Sections[2]);
}
```

The error that i'm getting is:

```
AfspraakBox does not exist in the current context.
```

I'm pritty sure it has something to do with the Hubs. Because in a new project without a Hub it just works fine. But i just can't figure out why and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? It may cause problems like this.

Comment: Yes i did, not working.

Comment: Not sure, but what if you remove "x:" from x:Name. Try just write Name

Comment: Just did that, still not working....

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a **XAML control** inside of a **DataTemplate**. That's a problem of **HubSections**. It uses **DataTemplate**, unlike **PivotItem**.